# Increase the performance cv2.calibrateCamera

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv

I am trying to make a live calibration tool that reads live images from the webcam and then do calibration.

I am collecting image points in real time, I do not have issues with speed of finding chessboardcorners like many do.

However, after collecting live data and storing all the image points and object points, I am calling the cv2.calibrateCamera() function.

I am having serious performance issues with this method when I have data from more than 50 images.

I have tried:

```
# loop:
#     read image
#     if pattern found:
#         calibrate the individual image and store results in array
# calculate the average of the array (assuming this is the real result)
```

But, the results obtained from this method are much different than the traditional approach of collecting all data and then calling cv2.CalibrateCamera() function.

I have also tried:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(self.camera.do_calibration())
    ret, f_ret, images_used = future.result()
```

in hopes of it giving me better results, but no luck.

The method that calls cv2.calibrateCamera():

```
def do_calibration(self):
    self.ret, self.mtx, self.dist, self.rvec, self.tvec = cv2.calibrateCamera(self.obj_points,
                                                                                  self.img_points,
                                                                                  (int(self.width), int(self.height)),
                                                                                  None, None)
```

I do not want my routine to give me immediate results, but I also do not want to wait like an hour for it to calculate the results.

Is there another solution this problem like a good usage of threads or flags that can help?

Comment: First thing, does the function return correct calibration results ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, it does.

Comment: But which ones ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Comparing to other projects I found on github, my results are similar. All of the matrix, distortion and vectors look good.